# expr / awk / sed: get git directory name from repo URL

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

Using *bash expr*, *sed* or *awk*, how can I determine the git base directory for a given git repo?

For example: **git@git.gitweb.com:/myModule-repo.git** => **myModule-repo**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on doing that with these tools,

```
echo git@git.gitweb.com:/myModule-repo.git | sed 's%^.*/\([^/]*\)\.git$%\1%g'
```

(find the substring from the last / until the literary .git) should do the trick, otherwise I would use

```
basename git@git.gitweb.com:/myModule-repo.git .git
```

which does the same (also, it is much more transparent and `basename` is as POSIX as `sed` and `awk`).

Comment: Both fail if you omit the / (slash) after the : (colon) which some applications do by default (e.g. gitlab).

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "git@git.gitweb.com:/myModule-repo.git" | sed 's|git@git.gitweb.com:/||;s/.git//'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
echo git@git.gitweb.com:/myModule-repo.git | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print substr ($2, 1, 13)}'
```